# android onclicklistener not open page

Tags: android

iam so sorry,my english language is so bad,my question is  if button is clicked ,for example [link] (http://example.com:xxx/exp.php) ,the button will send a query for execute php script,without any change in applicationn

but on java activity ,idont know to crete a class onclicklistener
im realy new on android dev app

here is my code

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ON"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OFF"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button" />
```

Comment: I am sorry because I do not really understand your question (and for laughing a little while reading your question). Are you trying to say that you would like a webpage to be opened in your Android application after the button is clicked? You do not want the webpage to be displayed in the phone's browser? Can you show the codes for the button's listener too?

Comment: iam so sorry,my english language is so bad,

Comment: Where is onClick prop?

Comment: Place a webview in invisible mode or height and width as "0". and on button click load your url to that webview. For onClickListener(...) refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803727/android-setonclicklistener-method-how-does-it-work

Comment: and please try googling first before asking any beginner level question on SO.

Comment: ok i will try to searc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button Click Event on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781468/button-click-event-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set a ClickListener at your button:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```